# Group-focus not working on my code using tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, laravel, tailwind-css, pseudo-class

my group-focus isn't working but group-hover and group-active is working, i code this using laravel 9. any solution of this?

```
<nav id="nav-menu" class="lg:block lg:static lg:bg-transparent lg:max-w-full lg:shadow-none lg:rounded-none  hidden absolute py-5 bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg max-w-[250px] w-full right-4 top-full">
                <ul class="block lg:flex">
                    <li class="group">
                        <a href="/" class="text-base text-black py-2 mx-8 flex group-hover:text-slate-500 group-active:text-slate-700">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="group">
                        <a href="/about" class="text-base text-black py-2 mx-8 flex group-hover:text-slate-500 group-focus:text-purple-400 group-active:text-pink-700">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="group">
                        <a href="/blog" class="text-base text-black py-2 mx-8 flex group-hover:text-slate-500">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="group">
                        <a href="/login" class="text-base text-black py-2 mx-8 flex group-hover:text-slate-500">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

try `focus-within:text-purple-400` (if my understanding of the question is correct)

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#focus

Answer (score 1):

Parent element of link (`<li>` tag) is **NOT** focusable element. According to [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#focus)

> An HTML user interface typically consists of multiple interactive widgets, such as form controls, scrollable regions, links, dialog boxes, browser tabs, and so forth. These widgets form a hierarchy, with some (e.g. browser tabs, dialog boxes) containing others (e.g. links, form controls).

`<li>` is not interactive therefore cannot be focused and that is why `group-focus` does nothing - the group is NOT focused (but link itself is focused). You may

1. Change `group-focus` state of link to `focus`

```html
// I removed all non-related classes

<li class="group">  
  <a href="/about" class="focus:text-purple-400">About</a>
</li>
```

2. Make `<li>` focusable by using `tabindex` attribute

```html
<li class="group" tabindex="0">  
  <a href="/about" class="group-focus:text-purple-400">About</a>
</li>
```

But I would not recommend second way because of [WCAG](https://w3c.github.io/wcag/guidelines/) (there is no need to make this element focusable)